# Autotools: Switching part of project to a different compiler

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, autotools

I'm working on a big, old, project that is using autotools. I would like to switch one part of the project to C++ (from C).

How can I switch the compiler used for a part of the project? I don't like the idea of completely splitting the project into two parts. The directory has only `Makefile.am` and I suppose I should register this somehow in `configure.ac`.

Comment: Usually the C++ compiler will be invoked for C++ source files, and the C compiler will be invoked for C source files. So where is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must define output variable CXX in configure.ac (the simplest way is by using AC_PROG_CXX macro), then all files with appropriate suffixes (.cc, .cpp) will be compiled by C++ compiler.

Answer (score 1):

In your source root, you mut have a configure.ac and Makefile.am with all the compiler options. So, you can create a subdirectory with a new configure.ac and Makefile.am with other options.

You only need to add this line in the parent configure.ac

```
AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS([subdir_name])
```

And add the new subdirectory in the parent Makefile.am

```
SUBDIRS= subdir_name
```

Hope can help.